# Issue with binding Image.Source in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Consider defining a trivial DataTemplate as follows:

```
    <Page.Resources>
         <DataTemplate x:Name="dTemplate" x:Key="DTemplate">
            <Image x:Name="image"
                Source="{Binding Source=imageSource, FallbackValue=./DesignData/foo.jpg}">
            </Image>
        </DataTemplate>
     </Page.Resources>
```

Where imageSource is a BitmapImage defined appropriately in the code behind.

Then set up its use somewhere in the page in the normal way

```
    <ListView x:Name="listView" d:DataContext="{d:DesignData Source=./DesignData/SampleData.xaml}"
           ItemsSource="{Binding oCollection}"
           ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DTemplate}" >
    </ListView>
```

Where oCollection is an observable collection of the correct type.

This all works fine at runtime.
The problem is that the page doesn't render in in Design View in VS.
Neither the ListView (nor the image) display.
The only fix I've found is to remove both of the explicit bindings in the XAML, as follows:

```
    Source="{Binding Source=, FallbackValue=./DesignData/Socrates.jpg}">
    ...
    ItemsSource="{Binding}"
```

Which is obviously not a good solution, since it now won't run.
I can fix the ItemsSource binding in the code behind, as follows

```
    thisPage.listView.ItemsSource = oCollection;
```

But I can't figure how to fix the Image source binding within the DataTemplate.  From looking around at other related Q&As it seems that trying to set binding for a DataTemplate within the code behind is pretty ugly, and non-recommended.

Any suggestions, on how to fix the XAML or the code behind, greatly appreciated.

Comment: imageSource is the name of Attribute in your XAML data source?

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't `Source="{Binding Path=imageSource, FallbackValue=./DesignData/foo.jpg}">` instead of `Source=imageSource`?

Comment: Try using below syntax

    `/ProjectNameSpace;component/DesignData/Socrates.jpg`

Comment: Hi @Mr.B - yes; ImageSource is a BitmapImage, and all works fine at runtime; it's just the VS Designer that seems flakey

Comment: Hi @Gaurav - just tried your suggestion; doesn't seem to help ie still no Designer display.

Comment: Hi @Clemens: Either

... Binding Path=imageSource ...

or

... Binding Source=imageSource ...

seem to work at runtime; there may be some subtle difference that I'm not aware of.  But neither work in the Designer.